# 2D list output formatting

Tags: python, arraylist, formatting, output

So, as stated, it is a 2D list. 6 columns (6 random numbers) within 7 rows.  The formatting for the out put should look like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwnHi.png

what I have for my code is this:

```
    print ("     ", 1 , "   ", 2, "   ",3, "   ",4, "   ",5, "   ",6)
print ()
for i in range(7):
    print (i+1, *Pizza[i], sep="     ")

print ("To", *sales_of_hours, sep="    ")
```

Pizza is my 2D list, and sales_of_hours is a list of the totals for each column, and I have another list named sales_of_day for the totals of each row, but when I try to add that to the loop like this:

```
    for i in range(7):
    print (i+1, *Pizza[i], sep="     ", *sales_of_day[i])
```

I get a syntax error. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the syntax error?

Comment: In the last print statement. It works fine without the "*sales_of_day[i]" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, `sales_of_day` is a one dimensional list, if so, you cannot unpack `sales_of_day[i]` , since that would most probably be a number.

Also, you do not need to manually give the spaces and all, you can use right asligment of `str.format()` , to achieve similar result , code -

```
print(' '*6,end='')
for i in range(6):
    print('{:>6}'.format(i+1),end="")
print('{:>6}'.format('Total'))

for i in range(7):
    print('{:>6}'.format(i+1),end='')
    for j in range(6):
        print('{:>6}'.format(pizza[i][j]),end="")
    print('{:>6}'.format(sales_of_day[i]))

print('{:>6}'.format('To'),end='')
for i in range(6):
    print('{:>6}'.format(sales_of_hours[i]),end='')
print()
```

The format `{:>6}` forces the string to be right-aligned within the available space (this is the default for numbers).

---

Demo -

```
import random

pizza = [[random.randint(1,9) for j in range(6)] for i in range(7)]

print(' '*5,end='')
for i in range(6):
    print('{:>5}'.format(i+1),end="")
print('{:>5}'.format('Total'))

for i in range(7):
    print('{:>5}'.format(i+1),end='')
    for j in range(6):
        print('{:>5}'.format(pizza[i][j]),end="")
    print('{:>5}'.format(sum(pizza[i])))

print('{:>5}'.format('To'),end='')
for i in range(6):
    print('{:>5}'.format(random.randint(10,50)),end='')
print()
```

Output -

```
> python a.py

         1    2    3    4    5    6Total
    1    4    6    6    2    6    9   33
    2    2    4    6    1    3    7   23
    3    1    4    3    5    7    1   21
    4    5    5    2    7    2    2   23
    5    3    1    6    8    1    7   26
    6    6    2    3    3    6    8   28
    7    3    9    6    6    4    4   32
   To   45   45   25   40   30   34
```

Answer (score 0):

after * it must be a sequence, so try to remove * from  sales_of_day

```
  space = " "*5
    for i in range(7):
        print (i+1, *Pizza[i], sep=space,end=space)
        print (sales_of_day[i])
```